# R highcharter mapline color does not change

Tags: javascript, r, plot, highcharts, r-highcharter

No matter what I try I have not been able to get the maplines (pointing out to the boxes on the right of the image) to change colors.
[see plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcVrP.png)

The default is a light grey that is barely visible (see pic). Here is a java script example of the highcharts template I am using where the maplines are silver:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/us-data-labels/

Update: by adding a data.frame with the lines and the colors I want them to have I can get one line to be colored, but not the others.

[image: plot with one colored line]

```
library(highcharter)
library(usmap)
library(dplyr)

##### get data #######
df <- usmap::statepop

us_small <- download_map_data("countries/us/custom/us-small")

leader_lines <- data.frame(color = rep(hex_to_rgba('#000000'),9),
                           leader_lines = rep('__separator_lines__',9))

##### plot #######
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series_map(us_small, df,
                    value = "pop_2015", joinBy = c("woe-name", "full")) %>%
  hc_add_series_map(us_small, 
                    leader_lines, 
                    value = 'color', 
                    joinBy = c("hc-group", "leader_lines"), 
                    lineWidth = 2,
                    type = "mapline")
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide all the data and code needed to run your chart? Especially us_small. I found this line in your other question "us_small <- download_map_data("countries/us/custom/us-small")" but now I am getting "Error in is.data.frame(df) : object 'tmp.df' not found" error

Comment: @raf18seb, sorry, looks like I only pasted part of the code in when I asked the question. Everything should run fine now. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Thanks for providing a working code. I have been trying for 1 hour but I wasn't able to find a solution in R, sorry. Hoping that someone else will help you or you'll find the answer on your own

Comment: thanks for looking at it! I'm still stumped, but I'll update if I find something.